# SQL Server 2008, Full-text index is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I am using SQL Server 2008 Express (Version 10.0.2531). When I try to use full-text index option, it is disabled, and not working. Although it is listed in the menu that appear on right clicking the name of a table in object explorer but it is disabled. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly full-text search isn't available in the standard edition on Express, but you can get [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express with Advanced Services](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=1842) which includes full-text search.

You might want to get a newer version though as 2008 is a bit old by now. The 2012 version of express with advanced tools can be downloaded [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx).

Comment: Thank you. Do i have to purchase any license key after downloading SQL Server 2008 express with advanced services? or it is free?

Comment: @DanielAziz It should be free just like the other Express editions as far as I know.